# Why do I keep getting a syntax error message (in Python) when using append?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

The syntax error is at line 9.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import math
x = []
y = []
n = raw_input('How many points: ')
number = n
while n > 0:
  x.append(input('enter x: ')
  y.append(input('enter y: ')
  n = n - 1
d = []
n = number
while n > 0:
  d.append(math.sqrt((x[n-1] - x[n-2])**2 + (y[n-1] - y[n-2]**2
  n = n - 1
d.append(math.sqrt((x[number-1] - x[0])**2 + (y[number-1] - y[0]**2
p = 0
n = number
while n > 0:
  p = p + d[n-1]
  n = n - 1
print(‘Perimeter =’)
print(p)
input(‘Press 0 and then enter to continue:’)
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, I am only a beginner in Python, so an easy to understand explanation would be helpful.

This is what is popping up in my terminal:

```
File "prg1.py", line 9
    y.append(input('enter y: ')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you paste the error traceback ?

Comment: `raw_input()` doesn't exist in Python3. If you are using Python2 the `input()` function can be harmful. You should use int(raw_input()) or float(raw_input()) instead

Answer (score 2):

There are so many errors of your code.

1. as a function, input and append both need (), so line 8 and 9 should be

   ```
   x.append(input('enter x: '))
   y.append(input('enter y: '))
   ```
2. the type of

   ```
   raw_input('How many points: ')
   ```

   is string, if you need add 1 to n, you should convert it to int using int() function.
3. append(),sqrt() also missing ')' .

Answer (score 0):

You forget to put closing bracket in line 9 and 10 or 8 and 9 (confused about the line num).

```
x.append(input('enter x: ') )
y.append(input('enter y: ') )
                            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you have openned two brackets and closed only one -

```
x.append(input('enter x: ') #one closing bracket missing.
y.append(input('enter y: ') #one closing bracket missing.
```

You need to do -

```
x.append(input('enter x: '))
y.append(input('enter y: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing brackets here

```
while n > 0:
  x.append(input('enter x: ')
  y.append(input('enter y: ')
```

should be

```
while n > 0:
  x.append(input('enter x: '))
  y.append(input('enter y: '))
```